# Why do people downvote newbies' posts on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, new-users

I am a newbie and there are many newbies on Stack Overflow like me. Since we want programming help, we are asking here after we have tried so much.

Some experts in that language downvote the post. But they should understand before downvoting the question. This is a hectic situation which makes us feel downrated and the experts only make us feel like that...

I request those who downvote others' posts... If you are going to downvote, better close the question... we don't want your answers or your downvote...

We want only teachers or the ones who advice us on the programming language.

I request Stack Exchange: please remove the votes. It highly discourages every newbie on this site and finally we get blocked due to downvotes.

There will be someone who downvotes this post also: Please get away.

I have been highly discouraged by this activity on Stack Overflow. Sorry.

Comment: Do you understand why downvotes exist at all? Have you used Q&A sites that don't have them?

Comment: Questions are typically downvoted because they are unclear, too board, or are otherwise off-topic.  Since you deleted your questions no one can provide you with any specific feedback on why your questions were downvoted.  So I will just suggest you read up on how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and do your research before asking a question.  If you do, you will find your questions are downvoted much less frequently.

Comment: The Stack Overflow user that is linked to the one that posted here has no questions - deleted or otherwise, @psubsee2003

Comment: Every single point you try to make pretty much proves you didn't take the tour for newbies nor looked at Help. At all. Whiny posts like this will bring on more downvotes - note on meta downvotes just mean people disagree with you - I'd recommend taking some time and learning what makes a good question before anything else.

Comment: ["downvotes are taken so damn personal..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/839601)

Comment: The solution is very simple: don't ask on Stack Overflow. Nobody is forcing you. No downvotes, nobody will be sad. Good luck.

Answer (score 9):

> some experts in that language put down rate on the post.. But they should understand before down rating the question.This is a hectic situation which makes us to feel down rated and the experts only make us feel like that...

And have you considered how posing your low quality questions has made *them* feel?  You've wasted their time by not posting an appropriate, useful question, you've treated the members of the community extremely poorly (as evidence by your meta post here) and not been considerate of them, and their valuable time.

What about all of the people posting *quality* questions that are having attention taken away from them because of your low quality questions?

> I request those who down rate others post... If you are going to down rate better close the question...we don't want your answers or your down rate...

Not all questions that merit a downvote are bad *enough* to merit a close vote, but many do, and presumably some amount of the downvotes you got *did* result in the same user voting to close.  Also note that there will be some users that don't have enough rep to be able to vote to close, even though they have enough to downvote.

> we want only teachers or the one who advice us on the programming language.

Then you're not in the right place.  SO isn't a place to get free private tutoring.   Hire a tutor if that's what you're looking for.

> I request to stackexchange ...please remove the vote... It highly discourages every newbie in this site and finally we get blocked due to down rate .

If they're continually posting extremely low quality content, and not improving their behavior or their contributions, then *this is exactly what we want to happen*.  If you're able to follow the rules and provide valuable contributions, then you're very welcome here, but if you're unwilling, or unable, to provide appropriate content that others find worth having, then you *aren't* welcome here.

> I have highly discouraged by this activity in stackoverflow. Sorry.

Being discouraged for *repeatedly* performing harmful behavior is, again, by design.  You've made it clear that you have no intention of improving your contributions, and your expectation of the site as your own free private tutors, means that *this is the expected result*.

Comment: And still every question deserves an answer...

Comment: @rene Is that a knock on me for answering this appalling meta question (in which case, fair enough) or just sarcasm?

Comment: I haven't decided on the sarcasm yet ...

Comment: And here I was hoping you'd refuse to respond to my comment question, for the sake of the irony.

Comment: I'm known for shattered hope....